# loop through all comboboxes in userform and validate with name and make them visible

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a userform in which pages and then on one page contain a lot of comboboxes all of them have a pattern in their name as per their location for example in first row I have 3 comboboxes their names are:
AO11, AO12, AO13

Second row has 04 comboboxes with following names

AO21, AO22, AO23, AO24

Third row has 04 Comboboxes with following names

AO31, AO32, AO33, AO34

and so on till 12~15 Comboboxes

X represents row number when which will start with X=1 because first row will always be visible.

once user press AddNewCMD it should make visible the next row of comboboxes with the following code:

```
Private Sub AddNewCMD_Click()
    
    If X = 2 Then
        
        Me.AO21.Visible = True
        Me.AO22.Visible = True
        Me.AO23.Visible = True
        Me.AO24.Visible = True
        
        X = X + 1
        
    ElseIf X = 3 Then
                    
        Me.AO31.Visible = True
        Me.AO32.Visible = True
        Me.AO33.Visible = True
        Me.AO34.Visible = True
    
        X = X + 1
        
    End If

End Sub
```

in AO21
2 represents row number
1 represent first combo in row two

however I realize that it will be very long code as if I add further rows in therefore I am search for a way that can loop through each comboboxes and validate x with its name and make them visible?

same goes for hiding the comboboxes.

Comment: This site might help: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm

Comment: Not clear what you want... Are there one single `AddNewCMD` button? If so, based on what to **add/show** a specific 'combo boxes row'? If each row contains such a button, does its name contain somehow a similar suffix to determine its position in terms of existing row? Can that used `X` be taken from anywhere on the form?

Comment: use Controls so you can define the name with the x variable, for example `Me.Controls("AO" & X & "1").Visible = True` An error will occur if the name cannot be found.

Comment: @FaneDuru YES! one button for adding rows of comboboxes and one button for removing rows of comboboxes x=1 or x=2 i'm not sure yet comes as userform initialize

Comment: I cannot get you... You said that the user form will have only the first combos row visible. Is that true? So, do you like to make the **next** combos row visible, after each such a button click?

Comment: @FaneDuru when the userform started only the first row will be visible all remaining rows will be visible=false at initializing stage

Comment: And? Please, answer the second clarification question. Based on what to set that `X`. I mean, for the first click to be 2, for the second to be 3 and so on?

Comment: @FaneDuru let say x represent current visible row, which will be set x=1 at userform initializing stage

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help if you cannot answer my clarification questions... **How the code to know which is the current visible row**? Based on what? Can you focus on my previous question and try answering it? Do you wan to have **only one visible row** at a specific moment?

Comment: I mean, if the first row is **the visible row**, do you like making visible the next row (the second) on the first click, the third on the following click and so on? If not, how do you like to make the rows visible? Based on which logic/algorithm? I asked above: "Do you wan to have **only one visible row** at a specific moment?" but no answer... If so, the "current visible row" can be determined... Otherwise, only you must tell us what you want accomplishing and based on what.

Answer (score 1):

Please, copy the next code in the userForm code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private nextRow As Long

Private Sub AddNewCMD_Click()
    Dim i As Long, ctrl As MSForms.Control, boolVis As Boolean
    If nextRow = 0 Then
        nextRow = 2
    Else
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
    Debug.Print nextRow
    For i = 0 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.count - 1
        Set ctrl = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls(i)
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            If CLng(Right(ctrl.Name, Len(ctrl.Name) - 2)) > 13 Then
                 Debug.Print ctrl.Name, ctrl.Visible
                 If CLng(Mid(ctrl.Name, 3, 1)) = nextRow Then
                    ctrl.Visible = True: boolVis = True
                 End If
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   If Not boolVis Then MsgBox "The row " & nextRow & " does not exist..."
End Sub
```

Clicking`AddNewCMD` button will make the next combos row visible. When the existing rows are all made visible, a message stating that no any row available will be raised.

You did not answer my clarification questions... But if only one such combo row should be visible (except the first one, or including), I can make a function to determine it, but this can be done only if you supply a logic algorithm based on what to proceed.

Comment: @Ibn e Ashiq Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, didn't it work as you want? If not, how do you want it working against it does?

Comment: Dear! I tried to solve it by myself, and some how got a way, which is really short and quick. I will update my question, with my suggestion. Thanks for your time and effort.